# Translate popup takes around 1 minute to open

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager

It takes more than 45 seconds for Tranlsate popup to appear. 
Customer is having a big bunch of items to send for translation, and it takes quite a lot of time - every time it takes 1 minute to open the popup.

Please let us know if there is any configuration which can improve the performance.

Let us know if you need any other information.

Comment: We could not find any error in the Translation Manager log file, but when we try to RightClick-> Translate on component "tcm:12-279902" we got following error in Tridion CM notification: 

"() Unable to determine if a valid translation job can be created 
The translation job details have not been loaded from the database. 

The translation job details have not been loaded from the database."

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. The community might be able to offer some suggestions, but please raise a support ticket with SDL for a proper investigation. Environment details, log files, tracing, and the translation manager configuration (properly anonymized) will help both in questions here as well as with Support.

Comment: Feel free to include all the information in your answer (update it) as well, it might help someone to help you. Also, it will be useful if SDL Support does give you an answer, to answer your own question with the details so that it benefits someone who experiences the same issue in the future.

Comment: one additional detail you may put here and also give to support is check with database profiler what is taking place at DB level when you try this call. Then use browser tools to see what call is taking the most time during  the popup opening process. If we\Support have those 2 details it should be helpful.